# DISCORD.NET I'm not able to make my bot send messages in the DM of a specific user

Tags: c#, discord.net

```
 ## **further on, I would have a Database with these users from discord, I need to send messages in the DM of each one** ##
    
       ## **I can't create a User and send message DM** ##
    
    
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Reflection;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using Discord;
        using Discord.Commands;
        using Discord.WebSocket;
        using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using System.Net;
```

´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´
namespace TutorialBot
{
class Program
{
//variables
static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

```
                private DiscordSocketClient _client;
                public CommandService _commands;
                private IServiceProvider _services;
        
        
                private SocketGuild guild;
        
                //log channel info
                private ulong LogChannelID;
                private SocketTextChannel LogChannel;
        
     
                //run bot connection
                public async Task RunBotAsync()
                {
                    _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
                    _commands = new CommandService();
        
        
                    _services = new ServiceCollection()
                        .AddSingleton(_client)
                        .AddSingleton(_commands)
                        .BuildServiceProvider();
        
                    string token = "OTg0NjUwMTkwMjgxNjY2NjQx.G5jW2T.dvzM...";
        
        
                    await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
        
                    await _client.StartAsync();
        
                    await Task.Delay(-1);
                    //now the bot is online
        
              
                }
```

´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´
public interface IUser : ISnowflakeEntity, IEntity, IMentionable, IPresence
{
string Discriminator { get; }
string Username { get; }

```
                    Task<IDMChannel> CreateDMChannelAsync(RequestOptions options = null);
                }
```

´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´
public async Task MessageUserAsync(IUser user)
{

```
                    var channel = await user.CreateDMChannelAsync();
                    try
                    {
                        await channel.SendMessageAsync("Awesome stuff!");
                    }
                    catch (Discord.Net.HttpException ex) when (ex.HttpCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Boo, I cannot message {user}.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What error are you receiving? If the server is returning "forbidden" then the user likely has direct messages turned off for the server in their privacy settings, or the bot is not in a server with them.

Comment: I'm not getting an error. it turns out that from there I don't know how to do it, I've read thousands of documents and so on, but it's hard to understand in parts. and the contents about are very few

Comment: You might be getting an error but you won't know because you only catch the Forbidden error code. Change your catch to a catch all and see if it picks up anything.